# Notation of a book on integration

Tags: integration, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X_i,X_j$ be two real random variables on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,P)$ and let $g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R_+$ and $K:\mathbb R_+\to\mathbb R_+$ be two functions such that $K(d(X_i)),K(d(X_j))$ are measurable.

I learned that
$$E(K(g(X_i))K(g(X_j)))=\int_\Omega K(g(X_i))K(g(X_j))(\omega)P(d\omega) \quad (a)$$.

Now, a book that I'm reading uses the notation:

$$E(K(g(X_i))K(g(X_j)))=\int_{\mathbb R_+}\int_{\mathbb R_+} K(u)K(v)dP_{g(X_i),g(X_j)}(u,v),\quad (b)$$
where $P_{g(X_i),g(X_j)}$ is the probability distribution of $(g(X_i),g(X_j))$.

**QUESTION** What is the precise relation between $(a)$ and $(b)$?

**My current view** I believe that $P_{g(X_i),g(X_j)}$ is the pushforward measure induced by the random vector $(g(X_i),g(X_j))$ and is defined by $P_{g(X_i),g(X_j)}=P\circ (g(X_i),g(X_j))^{-1}: \mathcal B_{\mathbb R^2}\to [0,1]$.

Let $f(x,y)=xy$ and $\bar K(x,y)=(K(x),K(y))$. The equality between $(a)$ and $(b)$ can be obtained from
\begin{align}
E(K(g(X_i))K(g(X_j)))&=\int_\Omega f\circ\bar K\circ (g(X_i),g(X_j))dP\\
   &=\int_{(g(X_i),g(X_j))(\Omega)} f\circ\bar K d(P\circ (g(X_i),g(X_j))^{-1})\\
&=\int_{\mathbb R^2} f\circ\bar K dP_{(g(X_i),g(X_j))}
\end{align}

Is my understanding clean?

Comment: It looks good, here are some other answers I got when I asked a similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3707726/proof-of-expected-value-property-for-product-of-independent-variables

Comment: Thank you for the reference. There, you assumed independence and then could use the product measure. Here, we cannot use such thing.